# NodeJS - Update MySQL Field after fetching new created id

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using NodeJS to insert a row into MySQL with a "title", "userid" and "opid" field ;

After insertion, I'd like to use the newly created id and the userid to create a new string called "audioname".

Then I'd like update a field called "audioname" with this new "audioname" string

Here's the code I'm using to create the audioname;

```
const audiopost = new Audiopost({
    title: req.body.title,
    userid: req.body.userid,
    opid: req.body.opid 
  });

   Audiopost.create(audiopost, (err, data) => {   
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Audiopost."
      });
    else 
      var newaudioid = data.id.toString();
      var newuserid = data.userid.toString();
      var hyphen = "-";
      var m4a = ".m4a"
      var newaudioname = newuserid + hyphen + newaudioid + m4a;
        res.send(newaudioname);
  });
};
```

And here's the model;

```
const Audiopost = function(audiopost) {
   this.userid = audiopost.userid;
  this.title = audiopost.title;
  this.opid = audiopost.opid;  
};

Audiopost.create = (newAudiopost, result) => {
  sql.query("INSERT INTO audioposts SET ?", newAudiopost, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("created audiopost: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newAudiopost });
    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newAudiopost });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you I believe,

```
sql.query("INSERT INTO audioposts SET ?", newAudiopost, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error: ", err);
    result(err, null);
    return;
  }
  const insertId = res.insertId;
  const userId = newAudiopost.userid;
  const m4a = ".m4a";
  const audioname = ${insertId}-${userId}${m4a}; //You can change this string in any format
  sql.query("UPDATE audioposts SET audioname = ? WHERE id = ?", [audioname, insertId], (err, res, fields) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: That worked! Can you edit in these tiny changes so I can select your answer? const insertId = res.insertId;
  const userId = newAudiopost.userid;
  const m4a = ".m4a";
  const audioname = `${insertId}-${userId}${m4a}`;

Comment: Glad to hear it! Of course, I edited my answer